# Recursive String permutation with repetitions allowed

Tags: java, string, recursion, permutation

Hi I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to get all permutations of a string but also allowing repetition of characters. (for example for string "ab" the output would be "aa, bb, ba, ab")

I have my code working correctly without repetition but I'm not sure how to go about modifying it to allow repetition of characters and only seem to find ways of doing this without repetition of characters.

Here is the code that I have:

```
    public static ArrayList<String> permutationsUnique(String word) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (word.length() == 0) {
        result.add(word);
        return result;
    } else {

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {

            String shorter = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1);

            ArrayList<String> shorterPermutations = permutationsUnique(shorter);

            for (String s : shorterPermutations) {
                result.add(word.charAt(i) + s);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

I would really appreciate if some one can guide me in the right direction.

Thank you

Comment: Are you required to implement this with recursion? Is the length of each permutation limited? For example, `"bba"`, `"aba"`, and `"abb"` are also permutations created with just the letters `'a'` and `'b'`.

Comment: in string "cat" output "tta" would be a valid output.

Comment: Is "ttat" a valid output in that case? Are my examples valid outputs in the original case?

Comment: a valid output shouldn't exceed the number o characters of original string while it can ignore some characters. "ttat" would be a Ok output if the original word was "cats"

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked long back, but I just worked on one java program to have permutation of integers with repetitions allowed. I am putting my code here, in case if someone needs it.

This program can generate permutations for specified length. i.e.
For integers 1,2 and lengthOfSinglePermutation = 2, output should be
11
21
12
22

For integers 1,2 and lengthOfSinglePermutation = 3, output should be
111
211
121
221
112
212
122
222

Hope this helps.

```
    public class PermutationsWithRepetitions {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] input = { 1, 2 };
    int lengthOfSinglePermutation = 3;

    // we need to check number of unique values in array
    Set<Integer> arrValues = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i : input) {
        arrValues.add(i);
    }
    int noOfUniqueValues = arrValues.size();

    int[] indexes = new int[lengthOfSinglePermutation];
    int totalPermutations = (int) Math.pow(noOfUniqueValues, lengthOfSinglePermutation);

    for (int i = 0; i < totalPermutations; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < lengthOfSinglePermutation; j++) {
            System.out.print(input[indexes[j]]);
        }
        System.out.println();

        for (int j = 0; j < lengthOfSinglePermutation; j++) {
            if (indexes[j] >= noOfUniqueValues - 1) {
                indexes[j] = 0;
            }
            else {
                indexes[j]++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my previous answer was somewhat unrelated. DELETED. This will definitely work :-

```
static void Recur(String prefix, String str)
{
 if(prefix.length()==str.length())
 { 
   System.out.println(prefix); return; 
 }

   for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
   Recur(prefix+str.charAt(i),str);
 }
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
    String str = "AB";
 }
```

The output is

```
AA
AB
BA
BB
```

Comment: What is prefix? I believe I need to keep the header of my method as:  public static ArrayList<String> permutationsUnique(String word) {

Comment: prefix is basically the string which will be added in the front using recursion. You have to go through the code to understand it's meaning because it is too complex to explain the recursive process.

Comment: and my method is different than yours. You have used arraylist but I have used string which is recommended.

Comment: I see... The recursive method is suposed to be a helper method that returns the string. This is how I was calling it: for (String s : permutations(keyWord))....

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution with a char array, but it works for any kind of array. Here, instead of print the characters (or whatever data type you want to), you can add your list and append the elements to it.

```
static void permuteAll(char [] a)
{   
    permuteArray(a, new char[a.length], 0);
}

static void permuteArray(char [] a, char [] s, int j)
{
    if(j == a.length)
    {
        System.out.println(new String(s));
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        s[j] = a[i];
        permuteArray(a, s, j+1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String str="ABC";
    int maxSize =3;
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    getCombination(chars, maxSize); 
}
static void getCombination(char[]chars, int maxSize){
   
  for(int i=0; i<chars.length; i++){
   combination(String.valueOf(chars[i]),chars,maxSize);
  }
}

static void combination(String prefix,char[] chars, int maxSize) {
if(prefix.length()>=maxSize){
    System.out.println(prefix);
}
else {
   for(int j= 0; j<chars.length;j++)
   {
      String newPrefix =prefix.concat(String.valueOf(chars[j]));
      combination(newPrefix,chars, maxSize);
   
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).